# lining up the from of an import statement in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I've tried to look around for the answer, but my search term fu is lacking. I'm using IntelliJ and recently acquired the latest updates. However, it changed my code formatting and I can't figure out which setting to change to make the "from" line up in a column.

That is, I have the following code:

```
import { class1 }        from 'mod1';
import { longerClass2 }  from 'myOtherMod';
import { thirdClass }    from 'mod3';
```

When I click command-option-l (I'm on a Mac), it changes the line to:

```
import { class1 } from 'mod1';
import { longerClass2 } from 'myOtherMod';
import { thirdClass } from 'mod3';
```

I would prefer that IntelliJ not change the alignment.

UPDATE: 
As requested, this is for typescript, but I would want it for javascript and any other transpilers, too. Also, I did not have this problem before the recent update.

Comment: It would help to better understand the problem if you add the tags for the language you are using since IntelliJ IDEA formatting options depend on the language. From the examples it looks like JavaScript. And the simple search for "align import from" in YouTrack leads to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24015.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not implemented yet, you can [vote for it here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24015).

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the link. Voted. From the first comment: `WS 2017.2 somehow broke my beautiful handcrafted import alignment :(`